# The problem while updating Eclipse Maven project An internal error occurred during: "Updating Maven Project"

Tags: java, maven

When i try to to do a Maven > update project on eclipse i get this error

```
An internal error occurred during: `"Updating Maven Project"`.

loader constraint violation: loader org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @3eb6549d wants to load class org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject. 
A different class with the same name was previously loaded by org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @310abad6. 
(org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject is in unnamed module of loader org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @310abad6, 
parent loader 'platform')
```

I'm using java `8`, eclipse version: `2023-03 (4.27.0)`

What could be the problem?

Cleaned Eclipse, checked plugins.

[image]

Comment: Try this (as a 'bad' workaround): close the project, then open the project.  That will effectively update maven.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem I could not find a fix but I do have a work around. At least it worked for me.  On **OS X** I removed the `.eclipse` directory found in the user root directory.

I downloaded a fresh `Eclipse Installer` in installed a clean copy of `version 2023-03 RCP/RAP environment`.

After launching the clean install I was offered to remove an outdated maven cache which I did.  I was then able to do a clean maven build.